# Laravel not working exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, server

I am trying to put my laravel project "live" but I am failing. I will start at the begin I got a VPS installed a `LAMP stack`, `installed composer` and `VSFTPD`. Went to /var/www/html and did a `git clone of my repo`. Changed apache to point to the correct directory, `chmoded the storage folder` and finally went to my server in the browser and got greeted by 2 `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`. After that I decided to check `storage/logs/laravel.log` and saw the following error:

`exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in /var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:7658`

and decided to do a `php artisan key:generate` and got this output `Application key [base64:(key was here but removed it here for obvious reasons)] set successfully.`. And checked again and got greeted by the same 2 `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`.

Right now i have no idea what to do anymore any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://laravel.io/forum/06-09-2015-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the default cypher in config/app.php as 'AES-256-CBC'. It requires a 32 character string, but the default key is "SomeRandomString," which is only 16 characters.

Either you change the cypher to 'AES-128-CBC' that works well with 16 character key, or you generate a new 32 character string for the key.

Do 'php artisan key:generate' on the command line. This will generate the proper key for you.

Update: Cache compiled had issues and a php artisan clear-compiled fixed it.

Comment: Do you have your .env file in there ? You probably have a .env.example that you need to rename to .env . Generally, .env files are excluded / ignored on the repo.

Comment: Yes i uploaded the env file from local machine to the server after git pulling.

Comment: Do you have the mcrypt module on your production server ?

Comment: @EdericoRocha is right. A common cause for this can be that the `mcrypt` PHP module is missing. If running `php -m | grep mcrypt` doesn't output `mcrypt` then you need to install it. If you're running a Debian based system such as Ubuntu on you production server, installing the module can be as easy as running `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` (or `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt` if you're running PHP 7).

Comment: @Bogdan `php -m | grep mcrypt` returns mcrypt .

Comment: @marsje What do you have in config/app.php, on `"cipher"` ?

Comment: @Ederico Rocha I have `AES-256-CBC` on cipher

Comment: Thank you. What do you have on your .env file on `APP_KEY` ?

Comment: @EdericoRocha `Kxw7dtXb3pS8nhD4km2sJqgCTCUGuwksz` is there

Comment: Ok now can you please verify that the server has at least PHP 5.5.9 and the modules OpenSSL, Mbstring, Tokenizer installed ?

Comment: @EdericoRocha php -v says `5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)`  and php -m says `[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache`

Comment: Ok, I am running a bit out of options. May be that your compiled cache got problems do can you do a `php artisan clear-compiled` for me please ?

Comment: @EdericoRocha I must have entered that command a 100 times allready and did nothing at all but did it again and it works! Thank you a lot for your time and help.

Comment: @marsje no worries mate. Glad you could get it fixed :).